# msi gs66 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS: every 3-4 attempts to end the session by hibernation ends with a black screen freeze

Tags: nvidia, hibernate

Syslog says:

```
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout ModemManager[1237]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.7019] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.7020] device (enp46s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.7116] device (p2p-dev-wlp48s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.7119] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.7121] device (wlp48s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout whoopsie[1913]: [18:14:33] offline
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout dbus-daemon[1116]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1119 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout dbus-daemon[1116]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout kernel: [24671.082254] wlp48s0: deauthenticating from 00:00:00:00:00:00 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gnome-shell[2558]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout wpa_supplicant[1158]: wlp48s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <warn>  [1643818473.8525] sup-iface[0x55d36bb6abf0,wlp48s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.8526] device (wlp48s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.8526] device (wlp48s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout avahi-daemon[1111]: Withdrawing address record for 0000::0000:0000:000:0000 on wlp48s0.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout avahi-daemon[1111]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp48s0.IPv6 with address 0000::0000:0000:000:0000.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.8840] dhcp4 (wlp48s0): state changed bound -> done
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout avahi-daemon[1111]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.186 on wlp48s0.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout avahi-daemon[1111]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp48s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.186.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout avahi-daemon[1111]: Interface wlp48s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout NetworkManager[1119]: <info>  [1643818473.8884] device (wlp48s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1633]: dbus-daemon[1633]: [session uid=125 pid=1633] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.11' (uid=125 pid=1778 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1633]: dbus-daemon[1633]: [session uid=125 pid=1633] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout wpa_supplicant[1158]: wlp48s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gsd-sharing[1778]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout gsd-sharing[1778]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout nm-dispatcher[189886]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Feb  2 18:14:33 nout wpa_supplicant[1158]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp48s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb  2 18:14:34 nout wpa_supplicant[1158]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp48s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb  2 18:14:43 nout kernel: [24681.001590] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:14:44 nout systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Feb  2 18:14:48 nout kernel: [24686.001572] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640Feb  2 18:14:53 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [0202/181453.567844:WARNING:exception_snapshot_linux.cc(427)] Unhandled signal -1
Feb  2 18:14:53 nout kernel: [24691.001555] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:14:53 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [2970:2970:0202/181453.827136:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(968)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512
Feb  2 18:14:58 nout kernel: [24696.001539] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:14:59 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [2970:3012:0202/181459.904152:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Feb  2 18:15:02 nout whoopsie[1913]: [18:15:02] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout kernel: [24701.001521] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system hibernate actions...
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout hibernate: nvidia-hibernate.service
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout logger[190195]: <13>Feb  2 18:15:03 hibernate: nvidia-hibernate.service
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Succeeded.
Feb  2 18:15:03 nout systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Feb  2 18:15:08 nout kernel: [24706.001503] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:13 nout kernel: [24711.001484] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:18 nout kernel: [24716.001466] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:23 nout kernel: [24721.001448] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:23 nout gsd-power[1804]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Время ожидания истекло (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Feb  2 18:15:28 nout kernel: [24726.001427] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:33 nout kernel: [24731.001406] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:38 nout kernel: [24736.001385] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:43 nout kernel: [24741.001365] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:46 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [2970:3012:0202/181546.193703:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Feb  2 18:15:48 nout kernel: [24746.001343] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:53 nout kernel: [24751.001321] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:15:58 nout kernel: [24756.001301] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:03 nout kernel: [24761.001280] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:08 nout kernel: [24766.001258] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:13 nout kernel: [24771.001236] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:18 nout kernel: [24776.001214] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:23 nout kernel: [24781.001192] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:28 nout kernel: [24786.001171] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:33 nout kernel: [24791.001151] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:38 nout kernel: [24796.001130] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:43 nout kernel: [24801.001111] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:48 nout kernel: [24806.001091] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:53 nout kernel: [24811.001071] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:16:58 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [2970:3012:0202/181658.458554:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Feb  2 18:16:58 nout kernel: [24816.001049] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:01 nout CRON[190569]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  2 18:17:03 nout kernel: [24821.001030] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:08 nout kernel: [24826.001009] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:13 nout kernel: [24831.000990] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:18 nout kernel: [24836.000970] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:23 nout kernel: [24841.000951] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:28 nout kernel: [24846.000930] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:33 nout kernel: [24851.000907] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:38 nout kernel: [24856.000885] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:43 nout kernel: [24861.000863] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:48 nout kernel: [24866.000840] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:53 nout kernel: [24871.000818] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:17:58 nout kernel: [24876.000795] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:03 nout kernel: [24881.000772] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:08 nout kernel: [24886.000750] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:13 nout kernel: [24891.000729] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:18 nout kernel: [24896.000706] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:23 nout kernel: [24901.000686] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:28 nout kernel: [24906.000664] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:33 nout kernel: [24911.000641] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:38 nout kernel: [24916.000617] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:43 nout kernel: [24921.000593] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:43 nout gnome-shell[2978]: [2970:3012:0202/181843.974044:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Feb  2 18:18:48 nout kernel: [24926.000570] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:53 nout kernel: [24931.000546] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:18:58 nout kernel: [24936.000523] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:03 nout kernel: [24941.000499] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:08 nout kernel: [24946.000476] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:13 nout kernel: [24951.000453] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:18 nout kernel: [24956.000429] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:23 nout kernel: [24961.000405] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:28 nout kernel: [24966.000380] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:33 nout kernel: [24971.000360] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:38 nout kernel: [24976.000335] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:43 nout kernel: [24981.000312] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:48 nout kernel: [24986.000288] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:53 nout kernel: [24991.000267] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:19:58 nout kernel: [24996.000245] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:20:03 nout kernel: [25001.000222] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:20:08 nout kernel: [25006.000198] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:20:13 nout kernel: [25011.000174] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
Feb  2 18:20:18 nout kernel: [25016.000151] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:2648:2640
```

I have installed `nvidia-driver-495`

With previous `nvidia-driver-460` I had same error:

```
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Error while waiting for GPU progress: 0x0000c67d:0 2:0:4048:4040
```

Kernel: 5.11.0-46-generic
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, it seems that I have solved this problem (two weeks without freezing).

I believe that the cause of this problem was the simultaneous installation of several different (incompatible versions) of nvidia sub-programs (for example, `nvidia-some-module-460` and `nvidia-some-other-module-475` at the same time).

Solution: force remove any nvidia apps and clean install nvidia drivers (version 495 or 510):

```
sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

after this my problem was solved.